# When a school is registering kids for college, what is that called?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

> During last years registration enrollment, we had 1,457 children register.

Is "registration enrollment" the best choice here?

The reason I don't just use the word "registration" is that a registration is a *particular* student's registration for the school. But maybe that word is applicable to each individual registration, as well as the entire process itself?

Comment: "a registration is a particular student's registration" -- have you checked? http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/registration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context shapes the interpretation.

For instance, if your example sentence was amended by dropping the word 'enrollment' from the tautologous term 'registration enrollment':

> During last year's registration, we had 1,457 children register

it is clear that here, 'registration' must refer to the process or period during which the *entire population of pupils* was being registered.

It would therefore be incorrect to say that in this context, 'registration' refers to the registration of an individual student.

However, if we take a different sentence:

> I need to finish typing up Amanda Smith's registration before I go to lunch

it is obvious that we are talking about the registration of a single individual.

Incidentally, *application, admission, registration* and *enrol(l)ment* are all possible options here, depending on which jargon term is used or preferred by the relevant educational institution, and in some cases on whether there is a screening-out process. (For instance, *application* tends to imply that not all comers will necessarily be accepted.)

Answer (score 2):

[*Admissions*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/College_admissions_in_the_United_States) may also refer to the process you describe. See for example [this](http://www.dailycal.org/2014/04/18/uc-berkeley-admission-decreases-9-percent-due-new-enrollment-model/). Therefore, something like:

> Last year, we admitted 1,457 children.

should easily work in context.

Comment: Admission is not necessarily the same thing as enrollment. For example, last year Columbia University admitted around 2,300 students, but only enrolled about 1,400; many of those accepted chose to attend other institutions or to defer their enrollment. But usage can vary by institution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Indeed not the same. As you illustrate, you can combine those words, including registration, to have something more accurate/precise.