# Difference between "Registration" and "Enrollment"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context, terminology

I'm developing a scholar system which I have to support english(and others) language. This system haves an *"Enrollment"* proccess. I've called it as "Enrollment" after some research because I could not just translate from my native lang(pt-BR) which could give a different meaning to the proccess.

I was asked about the term, so I gathered some resources to prove the term was better than "Course registration" and I found [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/214775/32175) that haves presented me some other terms like:

> application, admission, registration and enrol(l)ment

I would like to have an explanation about those terms to know which one is better in my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have asked, and answered [a similar question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/96714/registration-or-enrollment) on the Information Security SE. I think my own answer probably applies here.

Registration is the process of establishing your identity with an institution. For instance accepting your offer of a place.

Enrolment is when you provide your details and select your courses. Sometimes this can take place at the same time as registration though it may take place as a part of orientation (certainly did in my own experience!)

Reviewing the relevant pages of various university websites seems to line up with this for instance [Herts university](http://www.herts.ac.uk/university-life/registration-and-enrolment) (first one that comes up on a web search):

> Registration is the process through which you:
>
> - agree to be a student member of the University
> - agree to abide by the University's regulations and to become liable for fee payments
> - enrol on the modules you will be studying during the year

Basically, the terms *do* have different connotations, they're not quite synonyms though conflated in practice. Your selection of the term *enrollment* however seems correct, *if* the students username and credentials are established elsewhere.

Comment: In my case, the proccess offers to a new user a registration form in first step, then user can select the course and the payment method, as well. It is a complete proccess to the user(student) to start the lessons by itself. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Indeed sounds as though both activities are occurring as a part of the same process. I'm happy to have been of help!

Answer (score 6):

In American universities, you "enroll" in the university once, when you enter and begin studies. Before each term (semester or quarter) begins, you "register" for the classes you will be taking in that term.

Answer (score 4):

In this context the word register essentially means to have your name entered into a list. The word enrollment means to be registered into some type of official list in some type of official capacity.

You could talk about registering for courses, but enrolling is better.

Answer (score 1):

Enrollment is The Act Of Been Enrolled.enrolled is to be registered with an institution once tii you get off or to be signed up. While Registration is mainly a form fill system to provide a details for an institution.

Answer (score 0):

"Enrolment" (American spelling enrollment) is used in connection with universites,schools, courses and the army.

Comment: So, its better use `Enrolment` than `Registration` ?

Comment: I'm a non-native speaker, so I'm not competent for such questions. I have the hinch that the use of enrolment is to a certain degree a historical thing. Today we use computers and no paper rolls. That was a long time ago. In my view registration is just as well and the term registration is probably more frequent and better known as such a special term  as enrolment.